# After upgrading to 4.6 CiviMail HTML version is uneditable

Tags: civimail, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm doing some testing on 4.6 and after upgrading a site, I don't have the option to click into the HTML section when creating a mailing. The Plain Text section seems fine.

I have cleared caches and even tried changing the WYSIWYG editor to "Text Area" to see if it was something related to the editor, but it's the same:

[image: HTML mailing error]

Does anyone have an idea on how to get the CKEditor to show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an issue+patch filed for 4.6.1 at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16246. You can try disabling Drupal's aggregation as a work-around (by visiting "admin/config/development/performance"). If that work-around doesn't resolve it, let us know (since that would mean it's a different problem).

Comment: Thanks -- the aggregation setting works as a temporary fix.